# center documentView in center of NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, macos

How can I center my `DocumentView` (witch is subclass of NSOpenGLView) at `NSScrollView`?

Now it looks like this (gray area is NSScrollView bounds):

[image]

And I want it to look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `NSClipView` and override `-constrainBoundsRect:` to return the centered rect. This is discussed at the the 45:30 mark in the fantastic presentation from [WWDC 2013 - Session 215: Optimizing Drawing and Scrolling on OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/215/)

Answer (score 0):

Use an intermediate NSView which has the document view centered in it (set its frame accordingly and probably set layout constraints the way it should behave). Put that view in the scroll view.

Comment: `UIView` is `iOS` not `OSX` so because of that this answer is immediately wrong -1.

Comment: @Popeye But now that it says `NSView`
, it is immediately right :-) +1

Comment: Well, that's not true if one could transfer the knowledge to NSView which is trivial. ;-)

Comment: @Monolo true. I have removed my -1. AxelK true that it is trivial to just transfer the knowledge over but based on what the OP has asked they have specifically told us it is `OSX` so the answer should be based on `OSX` not `iOS` trivial or not.

Comment: @AxelK Do notice though that there is not a one-to-one relationship between the two architectures, but in this case it worked.